# How to format display for numbers alignment

Tags: ms-access, format, numbers, alignment

I have data in Access 2019 tables and want to combine them so they look like this **Value** **(Rating)**:

AchievementALL=-2..................2nd Value=9....3rd  Value=-64

AchievementALLRating=2.............2nd Value=10...3rd Value= 11

RESULT1=-02 (02)

RESULT2= 05 (10)

RESULT3=-64 (11)

Field Format=00

Here is my formula:  =([AchievementALL] & "   (" & [AchievementALLRating] & ")")

Unfortunately here is my display:

-2 (2)

9 (10)

-64 (11)

I am trying to make it look pretty so the numbers/characters align

Any and ALL help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field format doesn't work because expression uses actual values of fields and Format property set for each field individually is ignored.

One way to accomplish uses Format() function to pad with leading zeros, like:

`Format(AchievementALL, "00") & " (" & Format(AchievementALLRating, "00") & ")"`

That can be in a query or in textbox ControlSource (precede with = sign in textbox). Set textbox TextAlign property to Right.

Have to use as many zeros as there are possible digits.

Comment: I tried to add your format statement in the DATA (under properties) for the field and when I go to REPORT VIEW its asking for the value (as if your statement is a parameter)

Comment: This is the ANSWER.  I had to ADD an "=(" to the front and ADD an ")" to the end.  Thank you for this help

Comment: Sorry, took for granted you would know about = sign. Edited answer. If it resolves issue, please mark accepted. Don't see why need another paren.

Comment: Okay, now I understand your comment about adding paren - the additional pair surrounding entire expression is not necessary.